# SVN Merge priorities

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have a project in SVN which was on just one main trunk. I needed to add some comments to the code without disturbing the main development, so branched off at a common point.

Unfortunately, the developer needed to revert back to a version of code that was before my previously added comments (which were on the trunk). So, all my comments were effectively edited out of the trunk working copy. I think this was done by an overwrite or copy, as I can't see any evidence of versioning going on in the log. (As an aside, would he have been better branching from before my comments were added here? Bit late now, but may be worth knowing for future applications.)

A while later I performed a merge from the trunk into my branch, and it has had the effect of losing all my earlier comments from the files. (They are obviously still in the repository in older versions.) They were present in my branched files, but I suppose the trunk edits took priority, as they were later?

I'm just wondering how best to get around this and stop it happening in future, apart from not branching at all? There were no merge conflicts as my comments were separate blocks from the existing code.

Also, what's the best way to get my code comments back in again, short of manually editing them? They are extensive.

Comment: Are you sure the other guys checking in stuff isnt having merge conflicts? It sounds like the _other guy_ is just overwriting your stuff.

Comment: Why in the world would you **branch** to add comments??!! There are very few possible scenarios, like if you deliver your code to 3rd parties 'as is' and then comments are part of your deliverable. But such scenarios are extremely rare.

Comment: In any case, you need to merge changes from revisions where you committed your changes while **ignoring-ancestry**.

Comment: I tried the ignore ancestry flag, but it didn't work. The file I tried it on hadn't been edited within the branch, since he overwrote the code,so it's understandable, maybe, but I'd done a whole folder merge, so hadn't noticed it.

Comment: Actually I may have misunderstood what you were saying with the ancestry flags. I did a merge from the head.

Comment: Ideally I would prefer not to branch at all, but that wasn't considered an option. I'm just wondering if there is a way to re-integrate my changes back into their trunk HEAD code without doing it manually. If not then I'd better get cracking on it sooner rather than later and stock up on the coffee.

Comment: I meant merging your changes which were done on the branch back to the branch itself. Then (it is to be hoped) you can merge them back to trunk.

Comment: Ah, ok, so forget about trying to keep up to date with his HEAD code, which is now completely out of date with  my changes, and just try to re-integrate my code back into the trunk, while ignoring ancestry?

Comment: Not exactly: restore your changes to the branch with ignore ancestry; merge changes from the trunk to it (this should not affect your restored changes); reintegrate the branch.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12453/discussion-between-debs-and-malenkiy-scot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried malenkiy_scot's suggestion with a single file in a test repository, and think it's doing what I want.
To clarify, the steps I took were as follows:
1) Merge my file with a specific earlier version which had my comment blocks in, checking the "ignore ancestry" box.
2) Merge changes in from the trunk (after this my comments were still there)
3) Re-integrate the branch.

I think that's what was being suggested, but anyway it seems to be working as I want and will save me a lot of typing, so many thanks for the help.